# What is meant by 'see read(2)' in linux?

Tags: linux, manpage

I am assuming this message is linked to the Linux man pages. It mentions, for read(2), how read is read from a file descriptor.

So does *for more information see read(2)* just mean to check out the man page for read(2) for proper usage of the read command?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: In the terminal, try running `man 2 read`. It selects chapter 2 of the man pages, those about system calls. `man man` should introduce you to the list of chapters:

_0  Header files (usually found in /usr/include)
1  Executable programs or shell commands
2  System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
3  Library calls (functions within program libraries)
4  Special files (usually found in /dev)
5  File formats and conventions eg /etc/passwd
6  Games
7  Miscellaneous (including macro packages and conventions), e.g. man(7), groff(7)
8  System administration commands (usually only for root)_

Comment: or `man read 2` whatever flavor you like ;)

Comment: There are roughly 8 possible sections for the same manual page (that cover different aspects of the command, the configuration files, if any, etc..). To see what pages are available use `man -f read`. To read the one you identify as relevant from the list, use `man # read` Here it is `man 2 read`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means to read the 2 page for the function (read, in this case) from the man pages. The command is: **man x function** where x is the page number.

Answer (score 0):

To learn what it means, see `man(1)`.

(To see `man(1)`, type `man 1 man` (`man man` will most likely do too) in the terminal. Don't thank me, thank man.)